# 'ng build' keep creates 'angular.io.example'

Tags: angular6

Since updating angular to `v6.0.0` `ng build` with any other options creates angular.io.example. `ng serve` is working fine with or without `--prod` option.

I have no idea why it is not working.

My system versions are :

### Package                           Version

@angular-devkit/architect         0.5.13

@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.5.13

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.5.13

@angular-devkit/core              0.5.13

@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0 (cli-only)

@angular/cli

@angular/platform-server

@angular/upgrade

@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0-rc.11

@schematics/angular               0.6.0 (cli-only)

@schematics/update                0.6.0 (cli-only)

rxjs                              6.1.0

typescript                        2.7.2

webpack                           4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I found out that angular6 creates new directory under dist folder compiling with ng build. So that, firebase init command has to host the folder of dist/"your file". Unless you'll get firebase example page.